# tkinter variable does not change when changing Checkbutton state

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have a Window wich opens another window askig for the settings. But the BooleanVar I use to get the Checkbutton's state doesn't change. It does however when I call the settingswindow strait from the code without the other window.

This is the minimal code to get the

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.root = master
        SettingsWindow()
        self.root.mainloop()

class SettingsWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        rootSettings = Tk()

        self.rebuild = BooleanVar()
        chkRebuild = Checkbutton(rootSettings, text="rebuild", variable=self.rebuild, command=self.testFunc)
        chkRebuild.pack()

        rootSettings.mainloop()

    def testFunc(self):
        print(self.rebuild.get())

root = Tk()
mainWindow = MainWindow(root)
```

The output is always 0 when clicking on the checkbutton, evenso the output of BooleanVar is True or False.

What is the difference in calling SettingsWindow() from insite a class or outside? At least I think that is the reason it is not working.

I am using Pyhton3 in case there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two instances of `Tk`. For your second window you need to create a [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm). You also should never call `mainloop` more than once in your entire program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try making my second window as a Toplevel widget then.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample example for how to solve the checkbutton's variable not changing issue.
Key: for the second window, should use Toplevel, not use Tk.

```
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.fun = dict()

    def set_ui(self):
        Button(self.master, text='SecondWindow', command=self.fun).pack(side=LEFT)

        self.master.mainloop()


class SecondWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Toplevel()
        self.var = BooleanVar()
        self.set_ui()

    def printf(self):
        print(self.var.get())

    def set_ui(self):
        Checkbutton(self.root, text='press', variable=self.var, command=self.printf).pack(side=LEFT)


def call_second_window():
    second_window = SecondWindow()


main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.fun = call_second_window
main_window.set_ui()
```